# Generic Interface missing implementation

Tags: vb.net, interface, implements, generic-interface

I have a generic interface, even if I state the type when I implement it, it says the implemented classes misses all implementation of members.

The interface

```
Interface IBuilder(Of T)
    Function Number(ByVal literal As String) As T
End Interface
```

The implement

```
Class BracketsBuilder
    Implements IBuilder(Of String)
    Public Function Number(number__1 As String) As String
        Return number__1
    End Function
End Class
```

When I try to run the code, I get

> Class '**BracketsBuilder**' must implement '**Function Number(literal As
>   String)** As **String**' for interface '**IBuilder**(Of String)'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to indicate on the declaration of the Number function that it is the implementation of the Number Function defined in the Interface

```
Interface IBuilder(Of T)
    Function Number(ByVal literal As String) As T
End Interface

Class BracketsBuilder
    Implements IBuilder(Of String)

    Public Function Number(number__1 As String) As String Implements IBuilder(Of String).Number
        Return number__1
    End Function
End Class
```

If you type

```
Class BracketsBuilder
    Implements IBuilder(Of String)
```

and then hit enter, Visual Studio will add the Function declaration for you.